# How to disable ssl check in fsockopen ? (PHP 5.6)

Tags: php, ssl

Upgraded PHP to 5.6.5 and got errors with fsockopen:

```
fsockopen('ssl://74.201.154.90', '465', $errno, $error, $this->timeout);
```

Warning: fsockopen(): Peer certificate CN=`*.zoho.com' did not match expected CN=`74.201.154.90' in ...

Warning: fsockopen(): Failed to enable crypto in ...

Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://74.201.154.90:465

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> fsockopen('ssl://74.201.154.90', '465', $errno, $error, $this->timeout);

Try replacing `74.201.154.90` with `smtp.zoho.com`. That should do the trick.

Comment: To highlight the important part of the response *"First, try replacing 74.201.154.90 with smtp.zoho.com".* It is much better to recognize and fix the underlying problem (in this case access by IP instead of hostname, even if IP is not covered by certificate) instead of implementing workarounds without understanding fully what they are doing (i.e. allowing man-in-the-middle attacks against the connection). I wish it would be even more clearly shown in the response that disabling the certificate validation is not the way you should do.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich You're right, my answer was poorly worded. I wrote out my response to his title question before noticing the IP address in the `fsockopen` call.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich If you want to add your own answer, I wouldn't mind removing mine altogether.

Comment: No, your answer points out the real problem. No need to add another one.

Answer (score 2):

I should mention, there are two points in this question and answers:
1). What was the cause of this ssl error and what you should to do to avoid it? Right answer is: the cause was certificate and host name mismatch, you should try to avoid setting IP address instead of host name to avoid such errors (and avoid MiTM attacks among others), this is a good practice;
2). What should I specify in PHP file to disable certificate validation? I know this is a poor practice but I want to know how exactly disable this validation.